# How to make a dynamic animated movement for the graphics on the Silverlight website?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight

I have some graphic points in one graphicLayer on the map and I want to move their positions to the new places every 5 seconds based on some criteria. And these movement can be visualized dynamically on the website. I'm using ESRI Silverlight API.

How should I do that? It seems the map won't update its UI until the graphics' last movement were finished. Should I create a new thread to fulfill this dynamic visualization or there is any other trick?

Thanks,

Wei

Comment: +1 interested to see the answer to this.